# Get list of all values ​of an attribute in dynamo table without repeating

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries

```
I have a dynamodb table like this

name     company

Juan      comp1 
Camilo    comp2
Andres    comp1
...       ...
```

And i want to get an array like this using boto3 and python3.8:

```
[comp1, comp2]
```

Is there a way to avoid query all rows and then filter the duplicates?

Comment: How big is your table?

Comment: If companies are entities with lots of associated users, you should consider __normalising__ your data by creating a _company_ table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless company is part of the primary key structure, you will have to `scan` the entire table to determine all the unique values of the `company` attribute.  If getting a list of unique `company` items is a core access pattern in your application, you should consider storing your data differently.

Uniqueness in DynamoDB can happen in at least two ways.

1. Primary Keys - Include unique attributes into the primary key structure.
2. By enforcing the constraint when creating the item (e.g. using `ConditionExpression` and `attribute_not_exists` to enforce uniqueness).

If you *want* the company attribute to repeat throughout your table (which is totally fine), you might consider creating a secondary index with the company name as part of the primary key.  For example, you could have a Primary Key defined as a Partition Key of COMPANIES and a Sort Key of the company name.  That way, you could query the COMPANIES partition and get a unique list of company names.